# How to overwritePermissions for voice channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

For my parent category, the perms are set to everyone cannot connect to channels created and I want it so when someone reacts to the ✅, the bot allows anyone to join the voice channel. The code creates no errors but the permissions do not change. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                    message.channel.overwritePermissions([
                        {
                           id: message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, 
                           allow: ['CONNECT'],
                           
                        },
                    ]);
                      
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the '@everyone' role's permission overwrites, you will instead need to use `message.guild.id`

In addition to this, you're currently attempting to update the overwrites of a `text channel` to give `connect` permissions to everyone in the server which, let's be honest, does not really make much sense.
If you're trying to execute this command while the executor is present inside of a voice channel, here's what I'd suggest:

- First of all, you're able to pass the `user` argument in your reactions collector, therefore you could simply use `const member = reaction.guild.member(user.id)` to get the GuildMember object of the reactor.
- After the bot has found the GuildMember object, you can simply use the `member.voice.channel` function to get the channel object of the executor

And finally, after all of the above has been done, your code should look like this:

```
const member = reaction.guild.member(user.id)
    const channel = member.voice.channel
    channel.overwritePermissions([
        {
            id: message.guild.id,
            allow: ['CONNECT']
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If my code to create the channel is this:
```
message.guild.channels
            .create(name, {
                type: 'voice',
            })
            .then(channel => {
                const categoryID = '790702060835176461' 
                channel.setParent(categoryID)
                channel.setUserLimit(30)
            })
        
```
doesnt calling channel in the code confuse it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused since it's hard to understand when everything is in a single line xd

Could you message me on Discord (@Bqre#0001) so I could take a look?